# Regex for Word.AnotherWord

Tags: regex, vb.net

In Vb.NET I want to check a string if it is something like:

`package_name.Procedure_name` or
`PackageName.Procedure_Name_Something_Else` or
`package_name.ProcedureName`

So I need something like: `word.otherWord`

My problem is that I have tried many [regexs](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)  but I wasn't able to achieve my goal.
The latest regex expression that I tried is : `([\w-@]+\.)+([\w-@])` which matches up to the first character after the dot. 
Can anyone show me a direction or a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex should be

```
[\w-@]+[.][\w-@]+
```

Comment: No because your regex matches everything in something like :word1 word2 package.Procedure word3

Comment: Sorry I missed your edited regex. I tested and it works. Thanks